# Creating horizontal linear gradient with Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael, gradient

Im new to the Raphael library (looks great so far btw)

I was wondering how to create a horizontal linear gradient.

Here's my test code so far, mostly based from examples I've been looking at:-

```
$(function () {
    var paper = Raphael(0, 0, $(window).width(), $(window).height());
    var path = paper.path("M800,100 L800,600 Q801,610 802,600 T803,600 L803,100 Q802,110 801,100 T800,100").attr({
        "fill": "90-#f00:5-#00f:100",
        "fill-opacity": 0.5
    });
    var pathArray = path.attr("path");
    handle = paper.circle(pathArray[0][1], 350, 5).attr({
        fill: "black",
        cursor: "pointer",
        "stroke-width": 1,
        stroke: "transparent"
    });
    var start = function () {
        this.cx = this.attr("cx"),
        this.cy = this.attr("cy");
    },
    move = function (dx, dy) {
        var X = this.cx + dx, Y = this.cy + dy;
        this.attr({ cx: X, cy: Y });
        pathArray[0][1] = pathArray[1][1] = pathArray[6][1] = X;
        path.attr({ path: pathArray });
    },
    up = function () {
        this.dx = this.dy = 0;
    };
    handle.drag(move, start, up);
});
```

I see from the SVG spec on the w3 site there is an x1,x2,y1,y2 attribute in the actual linearGradient tag (although I'm not even sure if they handle orientation? http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#LinearGradientElement).

I just haven't used Raphael enough to know how to set that in my path attribute.

Cheers,
wacka.

P.S.
EDIT: Adding the following helps, but only works in IE:-

```
$("linearGradient").attr("x1", "0");
$("linearGradient").attr("x2", "100%");
$("linearGradient").attr("y1", "0");
$("linearGradient").attr("y2", "0");
```

ANOTHER EDIT: Interestingly, the above only worked in IE but the following works in both (even though the HTML is the same):-

```
$("defs").children().attr("x1", "0");
$("defs").children().attr("x2", "100%");
$("defs").children().attr("y1", "0");
$("defs").children().attr("y2", "0");
```

For some reason the following is 1 in IE and 0 in chrome:-

```
$("lineargradient").length
```

Now, although this works, surely there must be a nicer way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of a rect with a horizontal and a vertical gradient.

```
paper.rect(100,100,200,200).attr({"fill":"0-#f00:5-#00f:100"});
paper.rect(300,300,200,200).attr({"fill":"90-#f00:5-#00f:100"});
```

the first value in the fill is the angle of your gradient. You can apply that to your path.

Comment: ahh... so simple... I assume the next number is the percentage along the path?

Comment: I'll teach a man to fish... check out http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr, specifically gradients. It's explained quite succinctly there.

Comment: I did see that, but couldn't see how to turn the gradient around... my next problem is trying to basically make this (http://www.20thingsilearned.com/en-GB) with Raphael :P

Comment: I looked for so long on how to do this. This is a great answer for those who want a striped pattern but can't use "url(#whatever)" in Rafael paths. I put in a very long custom gradient and that did the trick.